# Generating a stable uuid ID across with clauses in GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery, uuid

I'm trying to generate a UUID within a with clause on GBQ and then use it in a subsequent with clause for a join.

```
with q1 as (
    select generate_uuid() as uuid 
), q2 as (
    select uuid from q1
)
select * from q1 
union all 
select * from q2
```

This returns two distinct uuid.

[image]

How would I go about generating an ID that stays the same across with clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with the reason behind this discrepancy.

TLDR; as of today there is no option to force BigQuery to materialize CTE results. It'd be useful when a CTE referenced more than once in a statement.

see below query:

```sql
with cte_1 as (
  select count(1) as row_count
  from `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` as sr
)
, cte_2 as (
  select row_count
  from cte_1
)
select row_count
from cte_1
union all
select row_count
from cte_2;
```

when the execution plan is examined, you'll see 2 `Input` stage for referenced `sr` table.

[image: execution plan for above query]

It'd be great if we have an option to materialize CTE results. *As I remember, oracle has this implicitly if CTE used more than once or explicitly via hints.*

materializing `q1` explicitly to table then use it twice might be a workaround. I'd prefer [temporary](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts#temporary_tables) table.
the drawback is; the cost may increase if your project uses on-demand pricing. *(rather than flat-rate)*

Answer (score 1):

Because subquery always executes each time it is called, so with your query, the generate_uuid will be called twice for both q1 and q2 tables.
I suggest you save the generated UUID to a table, then query from this to make sure the UUID is the same from both tables.